# Blur frame buffer content

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, blur

Can I blur not a texture but the frame buffer? The following shader blurs a texture:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec4 v_fragmentColor;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

uniform vec2 resolution;
uniform float blurRadius;
uniform float sampleNum;

vec3 blur(vec2);

void main(void)
{
    vec3 col = blur(v_texCoord);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(col, 1.0) * v_fragmentColor;
}

vec3 blur(vec2 p)
{
    if (blurRadius > 0.0 && sampleNum > 1.0)
    {
        vec3 col = vec3(0);
        vec2 unit = 1.0 / resolution.xy;

        float r = blurRadius;
        float sampleStep = r / sampleNum;

        float count = 0.0;

        for(float x = -r; x < r; x += sampleStep)
        {
            for(float y = -r; y < r; y += sampleStep)
            {
                float weight = (r - abs(x)) * (r - abs(y));
                col += texture2D(CC_Texture0, p + vec2(x * unit.x, y * unit.y)).rgb * weight;
                count += weight;
            }
        }

        return col / count;
    }

    return texture2D(CC_Texture0, p).rgb;
}
```

How can I blur not a texture pixels, but Frame Buffer pixels that is already drawn?

Comment: You'd have to copy the framebuffer to a texture and blur that. As a side note, the 2D kernel there is quite expensive. You could split it into separate horizontal and vertical operations is using Gaussian weights (although other functions are separable too). First link I found was [this](http://www.programming-techniques.com/2013/03/gaussian-blurring-using-separable.html).

Comment: I know this shader is shity. No weight precalc and the complexity is `O(n^2)` instead of `O(n)`. But why I have to copy framebuffer to a texture @jozxyqk?

Comment: Because you can't read the default fragmebuffer from a shader, that I know of.

Comment: @jozxyqk I have checked because GPU in parallel can process multiple pixels: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/10964/why-do-pixel-shaders-not-let-us-read-directly-from-the-framebuffer-or-the-depth

Answer (score 0):

You can apply that blur shader to texture that you've attached to the framebuffer as drawing to the framebuffer writes the pixel data to the selected colour attachment.

[This page](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Framebuffers) provides info on one way that it can be done by drawing the framebuffers colour attachment to the screen with a shader. It's in opengl 3.3 though but all the functions used should exist in opengl es 2.0.